# How to fetch supported public-key algorithms from OpenSSL 3.0?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

Currently I use `EVP_PKEY_meth_get_count()`, `EVP_PKEY_meth_get0` and suchlike calls to fetch list of supported public-key algorithms. However, OpenSSL 3.0 deprecates their usage. Which API should be used instead? Don't seem to find analogue of `EVP_CIPHER_do_all_sorted` which I use for symmetric ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looking into OpenSSL's `apps/list.c` gives an answer. Here is minimized snippet wich solves my issue (detecting supported OpenSSL features via CMake):

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x30000000L
static void
print_km_name(const char *name, void *param)
{
    /* Do not print OIDs for better clarity */
    if (!name || ((name[0] <= '9') && (name[0] >= '0'))) {
        return;
    }
    printf("%s\n", name);
}

static void
print_km(EVP_KEYMGMT *km, void *param)
{
    EVP_KEYMGMT_names_do_all(km, print_km_name, NULL);
}
#endif

int
list_publickey()
{
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x30000000L
    ...
#else
    EVP_KEYMGMT_do_all_provided(NULL, print_km, NULL);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```